# Struct does not provide a subscript operator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to loop through my adjacency list in my DFS search class, but its giving me this error: type 'AdjList' does not provide a subscript operator. I feel like it might be the way i saved adjList constructor for DFS but I'm not sure. I saw other solutions saw it has to be passed as a pointer so I changed `AdjList list` in the constructor to `AdjList* list` but that did not work. Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
    AdjList::AdjList(){}

    AdjList::AdjList(vector<Node> nodeVector){
        nodeContainer = nodeVector;
    }

    void AdjList::makeAdjList(){
        int temp;
        for(int i = 0; i < nodeContainer.size(); i++){
            connections = nodeContainer[i].getConnectionsVector();

            for(int x = 0; x < connections.size(); x++){
            innerList.push_back(nodeContainer[connections[x] - 1]);
            }
        
        adjList.push_back(innerList);
        innerList.clear();
        }  
    }

    //other AdjList functions

int main(){
    vector<Node> nodeContainer;
    nodeContainer = load();

    
    AdjList adjList(nodeContainer);
    adjList.makeAdjList();
   
    
    DFS search(nodeContainer, adjList);
    search.iterative(6,3);

}
```

**DFS.cpp**

```
DFS::DFS(vector<Node> nodeVec, AdjList list){
        nodeContainer = nodeVec;
        adjList = list;
   }

vector<Node> DFS::iterative(int src, int dest){
        vector<Node> vectorPath;
     
            
            list<Node>::iterator it;
            int i = 6;
            for(it = adjList[i].begin(); it != adjList[i].end(); it++){ //this is where the 
                                                                        //error is happening
                cout << it->getNodeID() << " ";
            } 
        return vectorPath;
    }
```

**AdjList.h**

```
class AdjList{
private:
public:
    list<Node> innerList;
    vector<list<Node> > adjList;
    vector<Node> nodeContainer;
    vector<int> connections;
    int temp;

    AdjList();
    AdjList(vector<Node> nodeVector);

    void makeAdjList();

    void displayAdjList();
};
```

Comment: What is definition of your class `AdjList`? Does it have `[]` operator and `begin()` method in it? What is **error message** for it?

Comment: I added it to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `adjList[i]`, C++ looks for an `operator[]` in the type of `adjList` which is `AdjList`. As this type doesn't have such a member function you get the error message that it's missing.

Supply a

```
std::list<Node>& operator[](std::size_t i);
std::list<Node> const& operator[](std::size_t i) const;
```

and return `adjList[i]` in both.

Comment: So how do I fix this? Because AdjList type actually consists of a vector<list<Node> > and I should be able to use that operator[]

Comment: @CrashMan123 See edit. It doesn't matter which members you have in your class. Operators are not magically added. You could say `adjList.adjList[i]`, btw.

Comment: Nice, I implemented that and it worked. What is this called and why does it work?

Comment: @CrashMan123  Have a look at [operator overloading](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). What you are implementing here is a custom subscript operator, that enables your object `x` of class `AdjList` to be subscripted with an `std::size_t` as such: `x[i]`. Where you might be confused is that the object in your outer scope is named `adjList` which coincides with your member identifier. It might be worth considering renaming the member. Additionally, you are overloading the `operator[]` member function so that you can call it on a `const` object as well as a mutable one.